# How can i remove from a List<string> that contain url's with specific strings in the url's?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    crawlLocaly1 = new CrawlLocaly();
    crawlLocaly1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    DialogResult dr = crawlLocaly1.ShowDialog(this);
    if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        crawlLocaly1.Close();
    }
    else if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        LocalyKeyWords.Add(crawlLocaly1.getText() + "," + mainUrl);
        crawlLocaly1.Close();
    }
}
```

When the user click the button6 it open a new Form with a textBox the user type in a keyword that can be a url or can be just a word. 
When the user clicks OK it's doing the line:

```
LocalyKeyWords.Add(crawlLocaly1.getText() + "," + mainUrl);
```

LocalyKeyword is a List and crawlLocaly1 is a new Form where im getting the text the user type in the textBox.

mainUrl is the current url.

So if the mainUrl is for example http://www.google.com

And the user typed in: Daniel

So in LocalyKeyWords List in index 0 I will see: Daniel,http://www.google.com
So I know that the keyword Daniel belong to http://www.google.com

Now I have this code:

```
private void removeExternals(List<string> externals)
{

}
```

Now the user can change and set the mainUrl at any time. 
I need that in the function removeExternals to check what the mainUrl is now and then to find the url in the List LocalyKeyWords and then to remove from the List externals all the places that the keyword that belong to the url in the LocalyKeyWords.

For example the mainUrl is now http://www.google.com
So I need to find what keyword belong to http://www.google.com
For example the keyword is Daniel: Daniel,http://www.google.com

So now remove all the places in the List externals that contain the keyword Daniel

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a `Dictionary<string, string>`

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, a LookUp or Dictionary would probably be best here. If you roll with a Dictionary:

```
//Declaration. This will map a Url to one or more keywords.
Dictionary<string, List<string>> LocalyKeyWords = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

...

//Adding an item.
if(LocalyKeyWords.ContainsKey(mainUrl)
{
    LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl].Add(crawlLocaly1.getText());
}
else
{
    LocalyKeyWords.Add(mainUrl, new List<string>(new string[] { crawlLocaly1.getText() } ));
}

...

private void removeExternals(List<string> externals)    
{    
     if(!LocalyKeyWords.ContainsKey(mainUrl))
     {
         return;
     }

     List<string> keywords = LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl];
     List<int> indices = new List<int>();

     foreach(string keyword in keywords)
     {
         //Accumulate a list of the indices of the items that match.
         indices = indices.Concat(externals.Select((v, i)
             => v.Contains(keyword) ? i : -1 )).ToList();         
     }

     //Filter out the -1s, grab only the unique indices.
     indices = indices.Where(i => i >= 0).Distinct().ToList();
     //Filter out those items that match the keyword(s) related to mainUrl.
     externals = externals.Where((v, i) => !indices.Contains(i)).ToList();    
}
```

This should do the trick, but I wasn't 100% sure what you were aiming at.

Comment: NickW about your code in the removeExternals in the line: indices = indices.Concat(externals.Select((v, i)              => v.Contains(k) ? i : -1 )).ToList();    the variable k is not exist. What should it be instead of k ?

Comment: NickW im aiming at this: In externals i have a List of many url's. For example in index 0 i have http://www.google.com and in index 1 i have http://www.microsoft.com....Now i want to give the user the option to set for him self what a local(Localy) url's means. For example if now the mainUrl is http://www.google.com and the user set as keyword for example: hello. so every url in the List externals that contain hello is called local(localy) its belong/relevant to the mainUrl . My program os crawling. If i set as mainUrl for http://www.google.com it iwll dig it levels.

Comment: So my goal in this part of my program is to set what local means. If the user set a keyword called google.co.il so now it should search find and remove all sites that NOT contain google.co.il in the url's. So in the end externals will have only url's that contain google.co.il. And if the user enter/change the keyword of http://www.google.co.il to Daniel so now in the end external should contain only url's that contain the word Daniel inside. The idea is to filter so only url's that contain the keyword will stay in externals. Maybe i did a mistake before. I want in externals to left with url's

Comment: that only contain the keyword inside. Not to remove from externals all the sites that contain the keyword ! I did a mistake. I want to remove all the sites that do not contain the keyword and leave in external only the sites that contain the keyword. So if the mainUrl is http://www.google.co.il and the keyword to this mainUrl is now google. So external should be in the end something like: index 0 http://www.google.co.il index 1 http://www.google.com index 2 google.google index 3 hi my name is google....and so on.

Comment: I have edited so that the `k` variable means what it should. In that last line of code I am checking for `!indices.Contains(i)`. If you want to filter out the ones that *don't* contain the keyword, just go `indices.Contains(i)` instead. Does that solve the problem?

Comment: NickW now your code seems to work but two things: 1. I need that in the end the filtered url's to be added to externals now each time externals is having a different number of url's inside i need that in the end there will be in externals X of url's that have been filtered. 2. i need the other way my mistake. i need that in externals to have all the url's that contain the keyword and now i have all the url's in externals that not contain the keyword.

Comment: 1. I'm not sure what's needed here. Are you wanting a specific number of Urls to be in the `externals` list after the method call?  2. I think making that change in my comment should ensure you get the urls that contain the keyword.